# Error: a type annotation may be needed

Tags: c#, f#

I am trying to have Name return the value of item.name where item is an instance of a C# class.

the fs file contains

```ml
namespace PatternMatch

type PatternMatch() = 
    member this.X = "F#"

namespace Items_
```

the fsx file contains

```ml
#load "PatternMatch.fs"
open PatternMatch

open Items_

type item = Item

let Name item = item.name //this line throws the error

let rec sentence s item  = function
    | s when s="Action" -> ""
    | s when s="Client" -> ""
    | s when s="Classifier" -> ""    
    | s when s="Container" -> ""    
    | s when s="ControlFlow" -> ""
    | s when s="Gaurd" -> ""
    | s when s="Name" -> Name item
    | s when s="ObjectFlow" -> ""    
    | s when s="Source" -> ""    
    | _ -> ""
```

`let Name item = item.name` throws the error. 
`Items_` is a C# namespace and `Item` is a C# class within.

The entire error is:

> Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.    C:\Users\jzbedocs\Local Files\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\addin\trunk\PatternMatch\Script.fsx   11  17  PatternMatch

Comment: You need a type annotation for `item` param of `Name` function.

Comment: isn't the line type item = Item the annotation?                     Item is a c# class.

Comment: @user3033411 `type item = Item` creates a type alias.
In `let Name (item: Item) = item.Name` param `item` has a type annotation of `Item`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let Name item = item.name` has no type annotation.  The parameter `item` is unconstrained other than by a member constraint which is not supported implicitly (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233203%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for making it explicit -- don't do that...)

It looks like you got confused because the parameter name `item` is the same as the type alias `item`.  If you want to explicitly make that so do this:

```ml
let Name (itemParameter:item) = itemParameter.name
```

I haven't checked if the parameter can have the same name as the alias, but it's probably a bad idea since it might be confused with the type parameter (we just saw this!).

Edit:  Ok, I checked.  You can have the parameter name be the same as the annotated type of the parameter, but it results in a horribly confusing type signature and implementation:

```ml
> let Name (item:item) = item.name;;

val Name : item:item -> string // EW!
```

If you're feeling particularly evil, you could even do something like this:

```ml
> let item (item:item) : item = item;;

val item : item:item -> item //Huh?
```

As an aside:

```ml
let rec sentence s item  = function
    | s when s="Action" -> ""
    | s when s="Client" -> ""
    | s when s="Classifier" -> ""    
    | s when s="Container" -> ""    
    | s when s="ControlFlow" -> ""
    | s when s="Gaurd" -> ""
    | s when s="Name" -> Name item
    | s when s="ObjectFlow" -> ""    
    | s when s="Source" -> ""    
    | _ -> ""
```

is probably better expressed as:

```ml
let rec sentence s item  = 
    match s with
    | "Action" -> ""
    | "Client" -> ""
    | "Classifier" -> ""    
    | "Container" -> ""    
    | "ControlFlow" -> ""
    | "Gaurd" -> "" //Guard maybe?
    | "Name" -> Name item
    | "ObjectFlow" -> ""    
    | "Source" -> ""    
    | _ -> ""
```

Here is a working example using a simple definition of `Item` (shown using the repl):

```ml
> type Item() =
    member val name = "" with get,set
type item = Item

let Name (itemParameter:item) = itemParameter.name

let test = item();;
test.name <- "test"
Name test;;

val it : string = "test"
```

Comment: I think you mean `... = itemParameter.name`.  If you found my post helpful, please mark it as the answer.  :-)

Comment: thank you all for the help. this style of programming seems very different from c#. Changing the line to 'let Name (itemParameter:item) = itemParameter.name' changes the error to 'field, constructor or member 'name' is not defined. it doesn't like me adding member under type item. nor does it like 'type item(name:string)'

Comment: Can you add the definition of `Item`?  Is it `Name` rather than `name`?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `type item(name:string)`, that isn't valid syntax.

Comment: The function is expecting type `item` (or in this case, type `Item` since `item` is simply an alias) to have a member called `name`.  The error is telling you that it doesn't have one called `name`.

Comment: Items_.Item is a c# class that contains a property 'name'. The fs file contains 'namespace Items_'.  The fsx file contains 'open Items_'. I want to pass in an instance of 'item' to the function 'sentence'. If 'sentence' matches 's' to "Name" then call the function 'Name' passing it 'item' and return item.name. 'item' is of type Items_.Item.

Comment: mydogisbox, I agree, just don't understand why. the class 'Item' does contain 'name' as a public property.

Comment: See my edit for a working example.  There must be something wrong in the code not posted.